# How to set custom environment variables using Google Cloud Deployment Manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, infrastructure-as-code, google-deployment-manager

Google Cloud Deployment Manager provides **deployment-specific environment variables** like Project ID and Deployment name.

```
def GenerateConfig(context):
  resources = []
  resources.append ({
    'name': 'vm-' + context.env["deployment"],
    'type': 'compute.v1.instance',
    'properties': {
       'serviceAccounts': [{
         'email': context.env['project_number'] + '-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
         'scopes': [...]
       }]
    }
    ...}]
  return {'resources': resources}
```

**Reference:** https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/use-environment-variables

I don't find any example to set any custom environment variable that can be used by my templates. If there is no support for this functionality, any hack on how to achieve this functionality will be very helpful

Comment: Google Cloud Deployment Manager, similar to terraform is an IaC service which will help us in provisioning, deleting and modifying the Infrastructure components. So, in general these variables will be fixed as they need to be understood by the cloud provider and in some cases like machine type the input is also selective that means you can’t enter your desired value you have to select from the list of options available. Can you provide more details on why you require this feature and what are you trying to achieve here? It will help us in better understanding of your problem or use case.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni, let's say I want to create a CloudSQL instance using Cloud Deployment Manager. The password should not be hard coded in my templates and injected into the templates via environment variables. I know this CLI doesn't support environment variables. Any hacky solution to inject an environment variable into my templates would be very helpful.

Comment: Dinesh you can make use for template properties for encrypting your secrets instead of hard coding them into your code follow [Best practices for using deployment manager document](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/best-practices#including_credentials_in_your_deployment) for more info. [Defining template properties](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/define-template-properties) will help you in understanding how to use template properties in your code.

Comment: JFYI I have provided the same as an answer please accept or upvote this if the solution satisfies you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Deployment Manager, similar to terraform is an IaC service which will help us in provisioning, deleting and modifying the Infrastructure components. So, in general these variables will be fixed as they need to be understood by the cloud provider and in some cases like machine type the input is also selective that means you can’t enter your desired value you have to select from the list of options available. Can you provide more details on why you require this feature and what are you trying to achieve here? It will help us in better understanding your problem or use case.

updates:

1. Dinesh you can make use for template properties for encrypting your secrets instead of hard coding them into your code follow [Best practices for using deployment manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/best-practices#including_credentials_in_your_deployment) document for more info. [Defining template properties](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/define-template-properties) will help you in understanding how to use template properties in your code.